# Connecting Pulse Sensor to RFDuino Simblee

Tags: arduino-ide, rf

I am trying to make a heart rate sensor watch. I am trying to do this using a Simblee (www.simblee.com) and a Pulse Sensor (www.pulsesensor.com) however they will not work! The original code from pulsesensor uses Timer2, which I commented out in favor of delay(2) (i'm new to Arduino and it seemed to work). I am getting readings over serial they just seem to be in a wave instead of a pulse. I need to get this working as I am out of time and money ;) Would anyone have any ideas on how I could get them working?

ALL CODE ON GITHUB (https://github.com/shadow85926/SimbleeArduinoCode)
Thank you.

Wave pattern:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw7tP.jpg